# How to add a sub collection to a document in firestore using react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Im new to react native and firestore so bare with me.

Im trying to create a document within a collection called groups (Which works).
Once it has been created im getting the doc ID of the created document and then trying to create a sub collection in it called admins and then a doc with an id for the current user and then setting the isAdmin field to be true.

I dont know if i'm making aa mistake or the logic isnt even right.

Im getting an unhandle promise rejection error and an output for the console.logs shown below

Document retreived with ID:  snPXEsZ8Bp7xQkJJtlj0
Current User ID:  vhZFUdJWeJXjcQHCVzVE3Y9meU33

[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: _firebase.db.collection('groups').doc(docId).collection('admins').doc(userId).add is not a function. (In '_firebase.db.collection('groups').doc(docId).collection('admins').doc(userId).add({]

```js
const submitGroup = async () => {
        await db
            .collection('groups')
            .add({
                userId: user.uid,
                groupName: groupName,
                groupImage: null,
                postTime: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
                groupPrivacy: selectedItem,
                
            })
            .then((docRef) => {

              // get & pass the doc id created above to var 
                const docId = docRef.id;

              //pass the current user id to var
                const userId = user.uid;

                const addAddmins = async (docId, userId) => {

                    console.log('Document retreived with ID: ', docId);
                    console.log('Current User ID: ', userId);

                    await db.collection('groups')
                        .doc(docId)
                        .collection('admins')
                        .doc(userId)
                        .add({
                            isAdmin: true,
                        })
                        .then(() => {
                            //Alert success

                        }).catch((error) => {
                            console.log('Something went wrong', error)
                        })
                }
                //Call add sub collection and pass parent doc ID and current userID
                addAddmins(docId, userId)
           
            })
            .catch((error) => {
             
                console.log('Something went wrong', error)

            })


    }
```

Comment: can you verify that `docId ` and `userId ` are not empty ?

Comment: Also, since you are already using `async` `await`why not continue with that ?

Comment: @CyrusZei yes I edited it and added console logs for both. the output is working for the docId and the userId. 
I dont understand what your 2nd comment means. I'm using 2 asyn awaits functions. One first creates the parent collection with a document and some fields with data then the 2nd one adds a sub collection with some fields and data.

Comment: hold on, I will write an answer to you. You can try that

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this code and just check that the `groupId` has the key `id` in it.

```
const submitGroup = async () => {
  const userId = user.uid;

  const groupId = await db.collection("groups").add({
    userId: user.uid,
    groupName: groupName,
    groupImage: null,
    postTime: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
    groupPrivacy: selectedItem
  });
  console.log("groupId:", groupId.id);
  
  const addAdmins = await db
    .collection("groups")
    .doc(groupId.id)
    .collection("admins")
    .doc(userId)
    .add({
      isAdmin: true
    });
};
```

Comment: this code gives me the same error. The first quesry to create the parent group works the second query to add the admin sub collection to the created parent group isnt working. I've narrowed it down to that

Comment: a tip I can give you is not to do it this way where the client is setting the `isAdmin` key. You should use `cloud functions`so that it sets the `isAdmin` key.

Comment: I will try this code soon and see what is happening

Comment: Okay i'll look into cloud functions. Reason I did that is whoever creates the group automatically is an admin.

Comment: yes, I understand that. How I do it is like this. You let the user create a group and then when that group is created you let the cloud function listen to that collection and add an array with the userId of that user. Why an array? because you can add more than one admin and also you can do a query where you do something like `where("isAdmin", "array-contains", userId)`. This will only get the groups that the user is admin in. Easier to filter out what groups the user is admin over for the user.

Comment: okay that makes the query to reteive admins much easier. Since you're here I might as well ask lol would it be a good idea to store memebers of the group in an array too? Considering it might have a loooot of memebers?

Comment: if you know that there will max be like 30-ish members then you can store the userID in an array, but if there will be much more members then I would use a collection with userId as document instead

Answer (score 0):

Okay I managed to figure out my problem i had to change the .add({}) to .set({}). I guess becuase the parent collection had already been made by the first query.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this for version 9 of firestore. It creates a message named collection with ID, messageID. It has a subcollection named messages with ID, subcollectionID.

```
const message_doc_ref = collection(db, 'message', "messageID", 'messages', "subcollectionID");
await addDoc(message_doc_ref, {data:"you data"}, { merge: true });
```